# Velocity - NPE when calling init()

Tags: java, velocity

I've been using Velocity for quite some time and never had an issue with it. However, recently, i came across an issue.

I'm using velocity to generate HTML code and send the generated HTML as an email. This process works 50% of the time. When it fails im getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:61)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:80)
        at org.apache.commons.collections.ExtendedProperties.load(ExtendedProperties.java:542)
        at org.apache.commons.collections.ExtendedProperties.load(ExtendedProperties.java:519)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.setDefaultProperties(RuntimeInstance.java:397)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.initializeProperties(RuntimeInstance.java:570)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:250)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:590)
        at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.init(VelocityEngine.java:136)
        at testapp.webapp.utility.velocity.VelocitySettings.<init>(VelocitySettings.java:48)
        ... 26 more
```

My code is as follows:

```
VelocityEngine ve = null;
try
{
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("resource.loader", "file");
props.put("file.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader");
props.put("file.resource.loader.path", Settings.getVelocityTemplatesPath());
props.put("file.resource.loader.cache", "true");
props.put("runtime.log.logsystem.class","org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.NullLogSystem");


ve = new VelocityEngine();
ve.init(props); //THE ERROR IS TAKING PLACE HERE
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  throw new Exception ("Error while instantiating the velocity engine", e);
}
```

I still can't explain why it's happening randomly. I researched a bit about this but couldn't find any clue yet. Anybody out there?

Comment: It looks like the only place an NPE could be generated is here: `props.put("file.resource.loader.path", Settings.getVelocityTemplatesPath());`.  Did you write that method, or is it part of this Apache package?

Comment: No that method is something that I wrote. However, I do print the path and it's displayed correctly. In other words, prior to the 'try' caluse i have a statement that prints the output of 'Settings.getVelocityTemplatesPath()' and it prints it correctly. So i doubt that the problem is this

Comment: What version of velocity are you using? And of commons-collections?

Comment: Velocity 1.6.3 & Commons Collection 3.2

Comment: Try upgrading to 1.7.  I have vague recollections of a bug like this being addressed.  Of course, to confirm that i'd have to search the bug tracker for Velocity Engine, but i'm too lazy right now.

Comment: So I updated Velocity to the latest release. As I said, the error happens randomly. It's a matter of time. At the time of this comment, no errors were generated yet.

Comment: ...aaaand we're back. The error happened again. Upgrading the velocity library didn't quite work. Any other ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I might have fixed the issue.

Unfortunately, in the problem statement above, I forgot to mention a very important detail. The code above is being executed multiple times. I have 10s or 100s of quartz jobs running, and each job will eventually execute the code above. This means, that each fired job will re-init VelocityEngine. Why this kind of behavior is causing the error above is something still beyond me. In order to overcome this issue, the code above resides in a normal JAVA class. I had to convert that class to a Singleton so that the initiation of VelcoityEngine is done always once. After these changes, the errors stopped streaming.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem. In my case the root cause was invalid jenkins cache on the test machine. After deleting it velocity started to work again.